# Tkinter enlarging graphs drawn on canvas without changing the canvas size

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am currently creating a GUI which plots data points from a textfile. I would like to enlarge the graph. Would like to ask if it is possible because everything I tried seems to yield no result. Below I attached the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEjok.png) of the graphs which I wish to enlarge. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the canvas [scale](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.scale-method) method?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the info. You really save my day :D